# Postgresql constraint no overlap between timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, constraints

I'm trying to create a table containing opening hours (for cafeteria's)
However I am having some issues with implementing the constraint. For each resto, the openinghours cannot overlap.

```
CREATE table openinghours(
    id serial PRIMARY key,
    start timestamp NOT NULL,
    duration interval NOT NULL,
    resto_naam varchar REFERENCES resto(naam),
    constraint openingstijden_duplicate_check EXCLUDE USING GIST (
        resto_naam WITH =,
        /* Check wether there is no overlap between the dates */
        tsrange(start, start + duration) WITH &&
    )
);
```

when I try to execute this SQL I get the following error:

> ERROR:  data type character varying has no default operator class for access method "gist"
>   HINT:  You must specify an operator class for the index or define a default operator class for the data type.
>   SQL state: 42704

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You need the btree_gist extension for this to work.  Execute `create btree_gist` and try again.

Best regards,
Bjarni